# Cutter failing to XREF even a simple 1 line 'Hello world'

Tags: cutter

[image: Text]

The disassembler yields 0 reference to the "Hello world" string!

Anyone knows what might be the issue?

IDA 8.2 Free and Ghidra find and shows the XREF as they are supposed to.

Comment: I'm not seeing an xref to the `hello world` string in Ghidra by default. Was it there after just the analysis?

Comment: Yep, Ghidra shows the XREF by default, and it is a clickable link that takes you to the fn using the data.

Comment: Hi and welcome to RE.SE. Could be a configuration issue in either of the tools. I see you seem to be using Rust. Care to share the binary or a way to reproduce your findings?